# How to use a custom class with interfaces and events as a collection

Tags: vba, collections, interface

I have kind of a complex scenario.

I have a custom class "clsModule".
There will be many instances of "clsModule". Each instance can have a collection of other "clsModule" instances. Each "clsModule" instance can fire events which should be handled by the "parent" instance of type "clsModule" that holds the variable number of child "clsModule" instances in a collection object.

I use suggestions of [this great post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163158/using-events-together-with-interfaces-in-vba).

The Problem is that events in VBA are only registered if the object variable in the handling class is **explicitly** defined via "WithEvents". But as the number of children instances of "clsModule" is variable, these cannot be defined explicitly.

The custom class "clsModule" contains a pseudo interface (rather a class than an interface, but I used the naming from the post above) that contains a custom event and function "notify".

Each child instance of "clsModule" in the parent collection "modules" fires the event "notify" correctly, but I do not know how to handle the event in the parent instance of "clsModule".

Any ideas?

Here is the code. For better understanding, I only mentioned the relevant class members.

clsModule

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents sheet_ As Worksheet
Private Type tThis
  events As IModuleEvents 'Pseudo interface; rather a class with I* naming
  modules As Collection 'holds variable number of "clsModule" instances
End Type
Private this As tThis

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

  Set this.events = New IModuleEvents

End Sub

Public Function constructor(wks as worksheet, _
  Optional modules As Collection)

  Set sheet_ = wks
  Set this.modules = modules

End Function

Private Sub sheet__Change(ByVal target As Range)

  notify "changed"

End Sub

Private Function notify(message As String)

  this.events.notify Me, message
  
End Function
```

IModuleEvents

```
Option Explicit

Public Event notify(ByRef module As clsModule, message As String)

Public Function notify(ByRef module As clsModule, message As String)
    
    RaiseEvent notify(module, message)
    
End Function
```

Setting it up in Module1 (Standard Module):

```
Option Explicit

Private source As clsModule
Private target As clsModule

Private Function test()

  Set source = New clsModule
  source.constructor ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  
  Set target = New clsModule
  target.constructor ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2), _
   newCollection(Array(source))

End Function

Private Function newCollection(items) As Collection

  Dim v, c As New Collection
  
  For Each v In items
    c.add v
  Next
  Set newCollection = c

End Function
```

Now, if you change the worksheet of instance "source", the function "notify" is correctly executed. But I do not know how to handle the event.